# Is there any way to swap columns in visual composer on mobile responsive?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, visual-composer

Is there any way to swap columns in visual composer on mobile responsive? 
I want to know it. such as we can swap columns in bootstrap using push or pull class. so can we make something like this in visual composer? i have uploaded images for assistance.

Actual Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFQIB.jpg

What i want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hPLR.jpg

Answer (score 12):

Yes. You can do that using `flex-direction:column-reverse`

Add `display:flex` to your `row` and then, with media queries, in mobile add `flex-direction:column-reverse` to the same `row`. It will `reverse` the column order and so the one that is on right in desktop will move up, and the one on the left will move down.

`display:flex` you can add it before mobile ( in general styles ) or just in mobile version when you need to add also `flex-direction:column-reverse`

See example below or [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/a83z11sx/)

```css
.vc_row { display:flex;}
.col { padding:0 15px;height:100px;border:1px solid red}



@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .vc_row { flex-direction:column-reverse}
}
```

```html
<div class="vc_row">
    <div class="col">
    text on left in desktop and on bottom in mobile
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    text on right in desktop and on top in mobile
    </div>
</div>
```

Read more about flex-direction -> **[Flex direction docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)**

**for iPhone** ( safari ) users `flex-direction: column-reverse` might not work as intended. Use

```
{ 
  flex-direction: column; 
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Vc composer has two classes:
**vc_col-sm-push-6** and **vc_col-sm-pull-6**

And you can use it for your question
Hope this help!

Comment: I wrote an article all about this at https://studiok40.com/using-push-pull-classes-with-visual-composer/ in case you need further explanation.

Comment: This is the best answer. Swap the order of your columns in the editor, and apply the classes to each column as described above. "sm" would be the breakpoint you want the switch to happen at (and above), and "6" being if they're 1/2 columns.

Answer (score 5):

Finally understood how works the push-pull. Sharing for others as I loose some time to figure it out.

You need to order the column so it's well ordered on mobile first, then you'll apply the classes **vc_col-sm-push-6** and **vc_col-sm-pull-6** to each column so it will then invert the columns as you want them in the wide desktop view.

It works perfect, no css to add, classes are recognized.

Thx @Gray for the tip! Too bad VC doesn't put a quick function for that, same as the hiding function.

Answer (score 2):

Change your structure a little bit, I believe it just drag and drop thing in Visual Composer.
whatever you want to show in second div, put at first place and give `float:right` for desktop and `float:none` for mobile.

here is [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/99p65dua/),

```css
div{
  width:50%;
  background:blue;
  float:right;
  color:white
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .first{
    background:red;
    float:none;
  }
  div{
    width:100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="first">First</div>
<div class="second">second</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just duplicate rows. Make one how you need it to look on desktop, and another how you need it to look on mobile. Disable desktop version on mobile devices and disable mobile version on desktop (column settings -> responsive options)

Comment: I was about to do this, but went with the push/pull columns instead.

Comment: its a bad way of doing this, as any changes we have to do on both columns

Comment: This also causes a duplicate content problem for SEO and unnecessarily increases the weight of the page.